# Can't download PDF on mobile/android app Using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I am using a jsPDF library for creating PDFs and downloading them. It is working on a mobile browser but in the mobile app, it is not working anymore. I searched that the doc.save() function is not functioning on the mobile app. is There any way to replace for save() function to work the download pdf on the mobile/android app?

Answer (score 0):

for mobile it wont work as it is a web feature to download pdf in mobile you will have to use cordova or capacitor plugin

Comment: I have no knowledge of Cordova. How will I use it in my project, will I add it to my project to work? Or will I need to redo all of it and use Cordova for the mobile App? My problem is I will need to work the generating and downloading pdf both in mobile app and mobile browser

Comment: what techstack are you using for app ?

Comment: The app is from our client. The content is our, we're just embedding it to their app/system that's why it is working on mobile browsers but not in their app.